# How to place exposed sort options as a dropdown above the grid? - Drupal 9 views

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-9

I have a view in D9 that has exposed sort fields. I want to place the exported sort fields as a dropdown above the grid results as below:

[image]

The grid above are the view results. I want to place the "date added" sort field as a dropdown above.

What i tried: I am trying to follow instructions in the end of this link - https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters/issues/1444758 to separate out exposed sort fields as a custom block but it's not working. Is there a different approach to solve this problem?

If exposed as a custom block I was thinking to place this on view header through Global:Cutom block field. Any help on how to do this please?